# AAD Configured REST API consumption in another AAD Configured REST API

Tags: azure-active-directory

Good Morning !!

We have a scenario where a client app hitting a intermediary service (REST - AAD Configured) , will be inturn routed to another Service Endpoint (REST - AAD Configured).  While doing so, we are successful in gettting accesstoken at client layer after hit to intermediary service. Now, Intermediary Service should consume an API of another service which is AAD Configured. For doing so, we have made use of BootstrapContext - for which we have got just token but not security token. We did try by making use of same token to consume, but in vain that wasn't helpful.

Exception while consuming REST Service from Intermediary service is nothing but " AAD Login Page HTML  " and status is 200 OK.

Kindly Suggest where we missed a piece and suggest needful.

P.S : I have added Intermediary Service in azure portal to client app to have access for consumption and Intermediary service has access to consume REST Service which needs to be consumed. Also, in all layers we are using latest nu-get package of ADAL.

Regards,

Jagadeesh

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you secured your API using the wrong authentication mechanism - unauthenticated or improperly authenticated API calls should never result in redirects or HTML pages. Also, the bootstrap token you receive is for the first service. The intermediate service should refuse that token as its audience is incorrect. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/ for the proper pattern.